# Auto Selecting a Value from Dropdown on Selection of Specific Value from Another Dropdown

Tags: javascript, html

Basically I am trying to figure out on selecting a value from dropdown on selection of a value from another dropdown select box.

```js
var gender1 = document.querySelector("#gender1");
var gender2 = document.querySelector("#gender2");

gender1.addEventListener("change", function() {
  var value = gender1.value;
  switch (value) {

    case "Boy":
      gender2.value = "Tipu";
      break;

    case "Girl":
      gender2.value = "Ayubi";
      break;

  }
})
```

```html
<select class="input_select" name="student_gender" id="gender1">
  <option value="Boy" '.$selected_boy.'>Boy</option>
  <option value="Girl" '.$selected_girl.'>Girl</option>
</select>

<select class="input_select" name="student_class_section" id="gender2">
  <option value="Tipu" '.$selected_boy.'>Tipu (Boy)</option>
  <option value="Ayubi" '.$selected_girl.'>Ayubi (Girl)</option>
</select>
```

[image]

Here is my complete HTML page code. Plz have a look to figure out the issue. So much thanks.

> 

```
    <head>
        <title>Jeelani High School & Academy® - '.$page_title.'</title>
        '.$jscript_data.'
        '.$css_data.'
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var gender1 = document.querySelector("#gender1");
            var gender2 = document.querySelector("#gender2");

            gender1.addEventListener("change", function() {
                var value = gender1.value;

                switch (value) {
                    case "Boy":
                        gender2.value = "Tipu";
                        break;

                    case "Girl":
                        gender2.value = "Ayubi";
                        break;
                }
            });

            gender2.addEventListener("change", function() {
                var { value } = gender2;

                switch (value) {
                    case "Tipu":
                        gender1.value = "Boy";
                        break;

                    case "Ayubi":
                        gender1.value = "Girl";
                        break;
                }
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    '.$header.'
    <table border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" class="tborder">
        <tr>
            <td class="tcat" colspan="2">Create New Student</td>
        <tr>
            <td class="trow1" width="70%" valign="top">
                <form name="CreateStudent" action="students.php" onsubmit="return validateFormStudent()" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <table border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" width="100%">
                        <tr>
                            <td class="tcat2" colspan="2">Personal Info</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td width="20%" class="trow1">Student\'s Name:</td>
                            <td width="50%" class="trow1"><input type="text" class="input_box" name="student_name" value="" size="20" maxlength="40" oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^a-zA-Z \,]/, \'\');" autofocus><span style="margin-left: 10px; color: #FF0000;">*</span>
                                <span style="float: right;">
                                    <div class="image-upload">
                                        <label for="file-input"><span class="profile_image_upload"><img src="./profile_image.png"> Upload Profile Image<input type="checkbox" class="input_checkbox" name="upload_profile_image" value="1"/></span></label>
                                        <input id="file-input" type="file" name="image" />
                                    </div>
                                </span>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td width="20%" class="trow2">Student\'s Gender:</td>
                            <td width="80%" class="trow2">
                            <select class="input_select" name="student_gender" id="gender1">
                                <option value="Boy"'.$selected_boy.'>Boy</option>
                                <option value="Girl"'.$selected_girl.'>Girl</option>
                            </select>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td width="20%" class="trow1">Father\'s Name:</td>
                            <td width="80%" class="trow1"><input type="text" class="input_box" name="student_father_name" value="" size="20" maxlength="40" oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^a-zA-Z \,]/, \'\');"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td width="20%" class="trow2">Contact #:</td>
                            <td width="80%" class="trow2"><input type="text" class="input_box" name="student_contact_no" value="" size="20" oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9,]/, \'\');"><div class="small_text">Comma separated numbers.</div></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td width="20%" class="trow1">Address:</td>
                            <td width="80%" class="trow1"><input type="text" class="input_box" name="student_address" value="" size="40"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="tcat2" colspan="2">Class Info</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td width="20%" class="trow1">Student\'s Class:</td>
                            <td width="80%" class="trow1">
                                <select class="input_select" name="student_class">
                                <option value="Play Group"'.$selected_pg.'>Play Group</option>
                                <option value="Nursery"'.$selected_nur.'>Nursery</option>
                                <option value="Prep."'.$selected_prep.'>Prep.</option>
                                <option value="1"'.$selected_1.'>Class 1</option>
                                <option value="2"'.$selected_2.'>Class 2</option>
                                <option value="3"'.$selected_3.'>Class 3</option>
                                <option value="4"'.$selected_4.'>Class 4</option>
                                <option value="5"'.$selected_5.'>Class 5</option>
                                <option value="6"'.$selected_6.'>Class 6</option>
                                <option value="7"'.$selected_7.'>Class 7</option>
                                <option value="8"'.$selected_8.'>Class 8</option>
                                <option value="Pre-9"'.$selected_pre9.'>Pre 9</option>
                                <option value="9"'.$selected_9.'>Class 9</option>
                                <option value="10"'.$selected_10.'>Class 10</option>
                            </select>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td width="20%" class="trow2">Class Section:</td>
                            <td width="80%" class="trow2">
                                <select class="input_select" name="student_class_section" id="gender2">
                                    <option value="Tipu"'.$selected_boy.'>Tipu (Boy)</option>
                                    <option value="Ayubi"'.$selected_girl.'>Ayubi (Girl)</option>
                                </select>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="tcat2" colspan="2">Fees Info</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td width="20%" class="trow1">Monthly Fee:</td>
                            <td width="80%" class="trow1"><input type="text" class="input_box" name="student_monthly_fee" value="" size="10" oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9,]/, \'\');" autofocus></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="tcat2" colspan="2" align="center">
                                <input type="hidden" name="action" value="do_create_student">
                                <input type="hidden" name="my_post_key" value="'.$mybb->post_code.'" />
                                <input type="submit" class="input_button" name="submit" value="Create Student" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </form>
            </td>
            <td class="trow1" width="30%" valign="top">'.$menu.'</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <br />
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is my complete HTML page code. Plz have a look to figure out the issue. So much thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking since the code you posted seems to do what you want.

Comment: Looks like your code is working, or are we missing something?

Comment: I have updated the above post with image. There you see that the option is selected but the other option is not auto selected

Comment: Problem is, the code is working here. But on my localhost, it isn't working. May be some other code issue? I have updated the first post with my complete HTML page code. Plz have a look at that to figure out the issue. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is to add *almost* the same event listener to `#gender2` as well.

```js
var gender1 = document.querySelector("#gender1");
var gender2 = document.querySelector("#gender2");

gender1.addEventListener("change", function() {
    var value = gender1.value;

    switch (value) {
        case "Boy":
            gender2.value = "Tipu";
            break;

        case "Girl":
            gender2.value = "Ayubi";
            break;
    }
});

gender2.addEventListener("change", function() {
    var { value } = gender2;

    switch (value) {
        case "Tipu":
            gender1.value = "Boy";
            break;

        case "Ayubi":
            gender1.value = "Girl";
            break;
    }
});
```

```html
<select class="input_select" name="student_gender" id="gender1">
    <option value="Boy">Boy</option>
    <option value="Girl">Girl</option>
</select>

<select class="input_select" name="student_class_section" id="gender2">
    <option value="Tipu">Tipu (Boy)</option>
    <option value="Ayubi">Ayubi (Girl)</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Problem is, the code is working here. But on my localhost, it isn't working. May be some other code issue?

Comment: I have updated the first post with my complete HTML page code. Plz have a look at that to figure out the issue. Thank You.